# Postgres extracting a polymorphic column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I have the following table called `feeds`:

```
 from_type | from_id 
-----------+---------
 user      |       1
 project   |       1
 user      |       2
 program   |       1
 program   |       2
 project   |       1
 challenge |       1
 project   |       3
 community |       1
```

and I'd like to transform it to this:

```
 from_type | user_id | project_id | program_id | challenge_id | community_id
-----------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------
 user      |       1 |            |            |              |         
 project   |         |          1 |            |              |         
 user      |       2 |            |            |              |         
 program   |         |            |          1 |              |         
 program   |         |            |          2 |              |         
 project   |         |          1 |            |              |         
 challenge |         |            |            |            1 |         
 project   |         |          3 |            |              |         
 community |         |            |            |              |           1
```

My reason for doing so is to have the reverse migration if we need to roll back. I managed to transform the bottom version to the top version with a `coalesce + update statement`, but I'm less sure how to perform the reverse operation.

Here's the up migration, what should the down migration look like?

```rb
class PolymorphicFeedTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      UPDATE feeds SET
        from_id = coalesce(user_id, project_id, community_id, challenge_id, program_id, need_id);
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      ?
    SQL
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you unroll your `up` method:

```
def up
  %w[challenge community need program project user].each do |type|
    execute("update feeds set from_id = #{type}_id where from_type = '#{type}'")
  end
end
```

then you can see the way back, just reverse the assignment:

```
def down
  %w[challenge community need program project user].each do |type|
    execute("update feeds set #{type}_id = from_id where from_type = '#{type}'")
    # ------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  end
end
```

That assumes that your table data isn't broken (i.e. that your `from_type` values match the `X_id` columns).

---

You could `connection.quote(type)` instead of simply wrapping `#{type}` in single quotes by hand but you know that the types are safe beforehand so that's not necessary. Similarly for `connection.quote_column_name` and the `#{type}_id` interpolations.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to do it as a single SQL statement, but I suppose that's not actually necessary, there are only a couple thousand records. And it's safe to assume the data is clean (we verified the data in production before approving this migration/refactor).

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys You could use dynamic SQL to do it in one query (i.e. SQL's version of `eval`) but I don't think it is worth the hassle for a down-migration that will probably never be used.

Comment: I concur, for a down migration that _I hope_ will never be used.  